# Comandos para dar permisos totales a una carpeta

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permisos

Buenas.

Necesto que por favor me pongan los comandos para que una carpeta que por defecto no permite crear ni eliminar nada en su interior, lo permita. Tengo Ubuntu Mate, y estoy practicando con PHP en mi localhost, pero cuando intento crear un documento de texto con la funcion FOPEN me dice "permiso denegado". Llegué a la conclusión que el problema no es PHP sino de LINUX. Y también por favor los comando para restablecerlo para cuando termine mis prácticas. ¿Es inseguro hacer esto? ¿Alguien podría entrar a mi local host desde internet o no? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En Linux para cambiar los permisos usa.

chmod -R 777 /var/www/htdocs

Sin embargo es mejor práctica cambiar el propietario de la carpeta. Para que le pertenezca a apache y el grupo a ti o al grupo de desarrollo.

chown -R www-data:tugrupo /var/www/htdocs

Asignar permisos para el propietario.

find /var/www/htdocs -type d - exec chmod u+r-w+x {} \;
find /Var/www/htdocs -type f -exec chmod u+r-w-x {} \;

Ahora a las carpetas donde php necesita crear archivos.

Hacer.

chmod -R u+w /var/www/htdocs/upload

Y los permisos para tu grupo.

chmod -R g+rwxs /var/www/htdocs
find /var/www/htdocs/ -type f-exec chmod g-x {} \;